# Counting number of active we requests without blocking

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

On a java webserver, I would like to know if there are any active web requests.

My first idea was something like:

```
    public static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

    public void processRequest() {
        count.incrementAndGet();
        // process my request
        count.decrementAndGet();
    }

    public boolean areThereActiveRequests() {
        return 0 == count.get();
    }
```

This obviously makes web requests block (albeit quickly) against each other waiting for a lock on count() when incrementing or decrementing - which we don't want for a highly scalable server.

Note that there may be synchronization issues with whatever code calls areThereActiveRequests - the value it returns may be stale by the time it's returned - but that's ok for my purposes.

Any ideas?

Comment: This would be better implemented as middleware. On the way in it increments the counter, on the way out it decrements. That way you don't have to tie your app request processing code to this monitoring code. To be precise, there is no lock on count. It uses CAS in a loop. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web requests **will not** block against each other waiting for a lock, as   AutomicInteger doesn't require any locks and utilizes Hardware synchronization primitive.

[Check this for details](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11234/)

Therefore your current code looks good for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hardware synchronization primitives aren't magical :)  They still have to deal with contention.  Depending on the architecture, atomic memory operations may lock the memory bus, limiting scalability.

Comment: Agreed, but they are much better than other locking mechanisms.